# Not enough memory error in C

Tags: c, memory, file-io

I am very new to C. I am creatin a file in C. But when i am trying to run below code I am getting Not enough memory error. i can not understand the problem. I cleared my temp folder but still the error exists. Any help please.

```
File *logfile;
logfile = fopen ("sample.txt","a+");
printf("\n logfile=%d\n",logfile);
if (!logfile)
 {
  perror("Error");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
```

Comment: "Not enough memory" would refer to RAM & swap, not disk space. Do you run in a severely memory constrained environment?

Comment: Do you want to print the contents of the file or the value of the file pointer? Be sure to switch on all compiler warnings.

Comment: You should tell how you compile your program (the source in the question is wrong and should not even compile), on which development system, for which target environment [if cross-compiling], and the operating system[s] you are using.

Comment: Could you give the system you are using, the exact source code, exact commands to compile it, and exact error message (in the C locale). Are you sure you got "Not enough memory" at runtime of your code? (the given code should not even compile, so you made a typo somewhere).

Answer (score 6):

You should always ask your compiler to give you all the warnings it can. With `gcc` it means passing `-Wall -Wextra` options to the `gcc` compiler.

If you did that, your compiler would have caught a lot of mistakes (by issuing warning or error messages):

1. You are missing the `#include <stdio.h>` directive
2. You should declare `FILE* logfile;` not `File *logfile;` Cases in identifiers are significant.
3. Your call to `printf` is wrong, because `logfile` is not an `int` as the `%d` format specifier wants. It is a pointer (to an abstract data structure), so if you want to `printf` it, use `%p`. Be awre that you won't know much about an `fopen`-ed `FILE*` handle from its address (what only should matter to you is if the result of `fopen` is `NULL` or not).

A general advice is to improve your source code till you get no more warnings from the compiler.

You should also learn to use a debugger (like `gdb`). Then compile with debugging information, e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g yoursource.c -o yourprog`

If you are on a Linux system (on which `gcc` and `gdb` are very usual tools), the `valgrind`, `strace` and  `ltrace` utilities are often useful.

Comment: @steffen: my 3 points are not hints, but constructive answers with a solution. So the overall answer contains solutions to the question in addition of hints.

Comment: That was meant to be a positive comment! Sorry if it sounded different.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: missing a header inclusion or misspelling a type name wouldn't lead to "not enough memory" -- so I'm with Steffen here: they're good hints that will hopefully help the OP to write more correct code... which is always a good thing.

Comment: I have no idea how Samurai got his "not enough memory" error. He did not explain that to us.

Answer (score 1):

`logfile` should be of type `FILE *` - change:

```
File *logfile;
```

to:

```
FILE *logfile;
```

and also change:

```
printf("\n logfile=%d\n",logfile);
```

to:

```
printf("\n logfile=%p\n",logfile);
```

Comment: Even better, to `printf("\n logfile=%p\n",(void*) logfile);` because `%p` wants a `(void*)` pointer.

Comment: @Basile: In C any pointer type can be implicitly cast to `void *` - no need for an explicit cast - redundant casts are a "code smell".

Comment: IIRC, recent GCC issues a warning for a `%p` for something not a `(void*)`; and long time ago, some weird systems (Unicos on Cray YMP) had a `(char*)` of different bit width [of pointers] than a `(double*)`, so the cast was a non-trivial operation

Comment: No warning here, even with `gcc -Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake (but I did got warnings related to `%p`, forgot the details).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you actually wanted to output the contents of the file, but if you really wanted to see the pointer, Paul R's post is probably more what you're after. Having said that, it's been a while since I've done this in C, but I think you'd want something along these lines:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFER 1000

int main(void)
{
  FILE *logfile = fopen("sample.txt", "r");
  char buffer[BUFFER];

  if (!logfile)
  {
    printf("Error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  while (fgets(buffer, BUFFER, logfile) != NULL)
  {
    printf("%s", buffer);
  }

  printf("\n");
  fclose(logfile);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Recent C or Posix implementations have `getline` to read an entire line, without bothering about a specific `BUFFER` size.